# Jersey REST Service - Resource response

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, tomcat8

I'm executing a REST tutorial using jersey 2.26.  I'm running in apache tomcat v 8.0.

I'm trying to change the response on my resource.  Initially it was returning, "Got it!".  Then I wanted to change it and I even tried adding a different resource with a new @PATH.  Even though I changed the path annotation on my resource, changed the value of the String I'm returning and bounced the server a handfull of times, every time I navigate to this resource, it's returning "Got it!"

Why doesn't it return "Got it! This worked" since I changed the return value?

```
package com.demo.jersey.message.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
* Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
*/
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

/**
 * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
 * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
 *
 * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {
    return "Got it! this worked";
}
}
```

Comment: I restarted my dev box and it is working now.  Interesting thing was when I would stop the server, I wouldn't get the response.  When I restarted the server, I got the old response eventhough I had changed the value in the return stmt.  Not sure if something was running in the background ?

Comment: Did you use curl/wget or similar? If so, caching would not be an issue. If you tested through an browser, you might hit some caching issues.

Comment: You are rebuilding your project each time, correct?